# Finishing Activity doesn't stop thread Android

Tags: android, interrupt

I have splash activity and 1 thread. Thread starts timer and after some time main activity will start.
Unlike on other apps I don't want to disable backPressed button in Splash Activity. I want when backpressed is pressed to cancel thread and finish activity. But I can't get it to work.
Here is my code:

```
        @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.starter);

                Thread Logo = new Thread() {
                    public void run() {

                        try {

                            sleep(1 * 1500);

                            Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                                    MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(i);

                            finish();

                        } catch (Exception exception) {

                        }
                    }
                };

                Logo.start();

            }
...


       @Override
            public void onBackPressed() {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                super.onBackPressed();
                this.finish();
            }
        }
```

But this doesn't stop thread, it only finish activity and thread keeps running in background(and ofc starts activity)

Comment: Make `Thread Logo object` Globally...

Comment: That worked. :O But is it safe to stop thread that way?

Comment: Ya off course why not>>> You should stop the Thread that you started...

Comment: I see, thanks. Could you write answer so I can accept it?

Comment: i would suggest to read on Android ui thread and worker thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Make Thread Logo Object Globally and do  Logo.interrupt();

You should stop the thread that you already Started before. and also as @TmKVU answer's `Thread.currentThread();` return main `UI/Main` Thread but you have to Stop your Logo Thread.

Answer (score 2):

Try this If you wish to stop the thread if **Back button** is pressed by the user:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
     // First check if the thread isAlive(). To avoid NullPointerException
     if(Logo.isAlive())
     {
         Logo.interrupt();
     }

    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do like this:

```
 private Thread thread;
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    // your logic
                    SplashActivity.this.finish();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    finish();
                }

            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        thread.interrupt();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

It will work as it works in my all apps.  Because when you inturrept thread then `InterruptedException` will be called. At that time finish your activity.

Answer (score 0):

`Thread.currentThread()` will refer to you `Main` thread, since it is the currently active `Thread`.

You should make a field from your thread, so you can access it in your `onBackPressed()`method. You can then call `logo.interrupt()`

Answer (score 0):

Use a **Handler** and **Runnable**. **Instead of the inner new Runnable, create it outside as an object then pass it as a parameter to the handler**. When you press back, call this method `handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);` to cancel the execution. Make sure to keep the variables in a global scope so you can access them anywhere.

```
    handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    }, SPLASH_SCREEN_TIMEOUT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it may help you.

```
private Thread Logo;
 @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.starter);

            logo = new Thread() {
                public void run() {

                    try {
                        if(!isInterrupted()){
                        sleep(1 * 1500);

                        Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                                MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);

                        finish();
                    }

                    } catch (Exception exception) {

                    }
                }
            };

            Logo.start();

        }
  @Override
    protected void onStop() {
      super.onStop();
      System.out.println("On Stop");
      logo.interrupt();
 }
```

...

```
   @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
           logo.interrupt();
           super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```